# On the bias of a confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, bias

I have that
$n(\hat{f}(x)-f(x)) \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$

And $\mu$ cannot be estimated.

Can I say that the bias of my confidence interval for $\hat{f}(x)$ is $\mu n^{-1} $?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a $\sqrt{n}$ in front?

Comment: You seem to have an estimate $\hat f$ for $f.$  What would your confidence interval be and what do you mean by a "bias" in it?  What does "$x$" represent?

Comment: By "biased CI" I meant that since we cannot compute $\mu$, the confidence we will derive is not centered on E[f(x)] and hence will have a coverage too low. Adam perfectly answered to my interrogation. Sorry for my bad formulation, I'll improve!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't usually say that a confidence interval is biased or not. That is a property of an estimator (here: $\hat{f}(x)$). But yes it's a result of Slutsky's theorem that if $n(\hat{f}(x) - f(x)) \rightarrow_d N(\mu, \sigma)$ then $E(\hat{f}(x)) = f(x) + \mu/n$ where $\mu/n$ is a bias.

The main operating characteristic of a CI is its coverage. We can calculate the % of coverage of the CI. For instance, if the 95% CI only captures the $f(x)$ 50% of the time, we can say the CI is anticonservative in that it reflects too optimistically the level of precision of the estimate. Coverage higher than the nominal level implies an estimator is too variable, too low implies the estimator is biased.